# Why are code blocks not being rendered in this jekyll site?

Tags: r, markdown, jekyll

Hi I am creating a jekyll site 'minima' theme and currently serving it locally. I uploaded a .MD file that I knitted a while ago from Rstudio Cloud in _posts. When I add this to my site as new post, click on the title, and load the file I do not like the way it looks. The code has no code block background, even though it does look like different formatting from the normal text. What do I do? Is this a theme problem? Here is an example of the page and the .md code. I would like to see the page have some sort of code block with a background color like what is seen in the stack overflow code block..

Any help is appreciated

[image: locally served website page]

````
## View datasets

Next, I viewed the head of these data sets

``` r
glimpse(sleep_data)
````

```
## Rows: 419
## Columns: 10
## $ Id                 <dbl> 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 150…
## $ SleepDay           <chr> "Tuesday, April 12, 2016", "Wednesday, April 13, 20…
## $ TotalSleepRecords  <int> 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
## $ TotalMinutesAsleep <dbl> 327, 384, 412, 340, 700, 304, 360, 325, 361, 430, 2…
## $ TotalTimeInBed     <dbl> 346, 407, 442, 367, 712, 320, 377, 364, 384, 449, 3…
## $ Total.hours.asleep <int> 5, 6, 7, 6, 12, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5,…
## $ Total.hours.in.bed <int> 6, 7, 7, 6, 12, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7, 6, 7, 7, 5,…
## $ subtraction        <int> 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, …
## $ differenceminutes  <int> 19, 23, 30, 27, 12, 16, 17, 39, 23, 19, 46, 29, 27,…
## $ X                  <chr> "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",…
```

```r
glimpse(weightLog_data)
```

```
## Rows: 67
## Columns: 8
## $ Id             <dbl> 1503960366, 1503960366, 1927972279, 2873212765, 2873212…
## $ Date           <chr> "5/2/2016 23:59", "5/3/2016 23:59", "4/13/2016 1:08", "…
## $ WeightKg       <dbl> 52.6, 52.6, 133.5, 56.7, 57.3, 72.4, 72.3, 69.7, 70.3, …
## $ WeightPounds   <dbl> 115.9631, 115.9631, 294.3171, 125.0021, 126.3249, 159.6…
## $ Fat            <int> 22, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,…
## $ BMI            <dbl> 22.65, 22.65, 47.54, 21.45, 21.69, 27.45, 27.38, 27.25,…
## $ IsManualReport <lgl> TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, …
## $ LogId          <dbl> 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e…
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not closing your code blocks with back ticks. They should look this:

> ```r 
> glimpse(sleep_data) 
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The theme defines the code block formatting here:
https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/ffdb3210adabbd0a04f567ff88aa716928d664d0/_sass/minima/_base.scss#L162

The sass variable for the background color depends on the theme, for classic it is defined here:
https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/ffdb3210adabbd0a04f567ff88aa716928d664d0/_sass/minima/skins/classic.scss#L11

You will need to modify the CSS or add custom styles to change the defaults.